# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of null" Error when trying to use mootools with joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools

I want to create a button that shows/hides (toggles) certain rows of a table (trs), basically a dropdown table. I am using JCE as the editor and im writing the javascript code directly into the article through the JCE editor. When I open the page i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of null. It leads me to these lines inside the mootools-more.js file:

```
var wrapper = element.retrieve('wrapper'),
        styles = element.getStyles('margin', 'position', 'overflow');

    if (options.hideOverflow) styles = Object.append(styles, {overflow: 'hidden'});
    if (options.wrapper) wrapper = document.id(options.wrapper).setStyles(styles);

    if (!wrapper) wrapper = new Element('div', {
        styles: styles
    }).wraps(element);
```

I got the code from this example: http://demos111.mootools.net/Fx.Slide

Comment: That error means `element` is not what you think. Where does that variable come from in your code?

Comment: as Sergio says, `element` needs to point to a HTMLElement object - eg. `var element = document.id('foo')`.